# proof by contraposition in agda using solvers

Tags: math, solver, proof, agda, agda-stdlib

can you use the Nat solver in agda-stdlib for proof by contradiction? In particular I have a gnarly bit of algebra I'd rather not do by hand, but I'm not sure how to use a solver to make my life easier. For reference this is the result I want to prove:

```
{n m : ℕ} → 3 + (n + (3 + (n + (3 + (n + n * (3 + n)))))) ≡ 1 + m + (1 + m + (1 + m + 0)) + 2 → ⊥
```

Comment: You can use the solver to simplify each of the sides, but I don't think it's set up to prove anything other than equations. If ℕ is the free commutative semiring on one generator (which I believe it is, but I can't remember), then it should in principle be possible to augment the existing solver to prove inequalities between polynomials. Also, “proof of a negation” or “refutation” is more correct than “proof by contradiction” in this case.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, your statement is not an inequality of polynomials – it's the non-existence of a solution to a Diophantine equation. That's a lot harder to solve. But maybe you meant `({n m : ℕ} → ...) → ⊥`.